# put a metal net around a soccer field

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure, sentence-request

Please imagine a local soccer field in a neighborhood in which a bunch of youths everyday play in it. Once, when they gather together at the sight, they notice that there is a problem. Some people have put a metal net around it for some reason and they cannot enter the field. There is someone missing yet (e.g. he is an always late member of the group.) The guy calls one of the present friends at the sight and asks if they have changed their clothes to assure they are playing or not yet. His friend tells him (through the phone):

> - Hey Mathew. There is something wrong today! Guess what?
>
> What?!
>
> Some people have **put a metal net around the field.**

[image]

I'm certain that the way I expressed my intention is not a natural way. I would appreciate it if someone tells me how shall I say it in a normal way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What usually gets put up around playing fields especially in urban environments is a

> fence

He would say

> They put up a **fence** around the playing field.

[image]

specifically it is a chain-link fence.